# What's the difference between Channel Capacity and Bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth

The definitions of Channel Capacity and Bandwidth I read are exactly the same, so what's the difference between them/their exact definitions?

The Nyquist formula is C = 2 * B * log<sub>2</sub> M, so they can't mean the same thing.

- B = frequency bandwidth
- M = number of signal levels
- Channel Capacity source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-data-rate-channel-capacity-for-noiseless-and-noisy-channels/
- Bandwidth source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)

Comment: They probably are the same, as there is no "official" definition of channel capacity.  If you include the context of the term (a full quote or reference), we can say for sure.

Comment: But the Nyquist formula is C=2Blog2M, so they can't be the same

Comment: Please include the reference where you see the term "channel capacity,"

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: "Channel capacity" is the theoretical maximum of a channel (cable, WDM channel, ...), "bandwidth" is the (currently) usable data rate. imho.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is confusion between the definitions electrical engineers and computer scientists give to bandwidth:
for electrical engineers bandwidth is a physical property and limitation of a trasmission channel,and it's measured in Hertz and it's an analog bandwidth.
For computer scientists bandwidth is equal to the capacity or maximum data rate of a channel, it's a digital bandwidth and it's measured in bit/s.
The two are related by the Nyquist formula,  C = 2 * B * log<sub>2</sub> M,where B is the analog bandwidth (Hertz) of the physical channel used for digital transmission,M is the number of discrete levels used to digitally represent the signal,C is the capacity or maximum data rate or digital bandwidth (bit/s) of the channel.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of the context, what is referred to as "channel capacity," I would call "Throughput."